# Not able to find second highest salary from emp table without using limit and sub-query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
max(a.salary) as salary
FROM
tbl_emp as a,
tbl_emp as b
WHERE
a.salary < b.salary
and a.dept_Id = '57'
and a.Date_of_joining between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 23:59:59';
```

Comment: am i doing any mistake please let me know

Comment: do you have an id column

Answer (score 1):

This is just a visualization with rownum.

```
create table tbl_emp
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    salary int not null,
    key(salary) -- with few rows, not used, run thru EXPLAIN cmd to prove it
);
insert tbl_emp(salary) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);  -- affordable employees

set @rownum:=0;
select * from
(
    select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum,id,salary
    from tbl_emp
    order by salary desc
    limit 2
) xxx
where rownum=2;

+--------+----+--------+
| rownum | id | salary |
+--------+----+--------+
|      2 |  4 |      4 |
+--------+----+--------+
```

Comment: Yes, that's the only way if it has to be done without limit/subquery.

Comment: yeah @Rahul. Unless we do funny things like insert into a new table and delete rows, then a select :>

Comment: Ahh!!! it's MySQL else would have already posted an answer using `ROW_NUMBER()` that's a straight forward way... but MySQL???

Comment: had to mimic rownum with mysql

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do something like below using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause

```
SELECT
salary as secondHighest_salary
FROM
tbl_emp 
WHERE dept_Id = '57'
and Date_of_joining between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 23:59:59'
ORDER BY salary desc
LIMIT 1,2;
```

Comment: i know it but i don't want to use limit and sub-query as i mentioned in heading

Comment: @KaranKumarMahto, yeah did got that after posting the answer but out of curiosity why can't you use limit/subquery? Is that a limitation (or) is it a homework question?